# What are the common ways for deletion local/client objects using REST API?

Tags: json, web-services, api, rest, restful-architecture

Is there common design pattern for dispatching deleted objects to the requestor (client of the API)?

Challenges we are having:

1. When object is deleted on the API completely, client will not know
   that object is gone and will keep it locally (as API only shows objects changed after the certain date)
2. If we enable object's property to show that is deleted (ex. "deleted = TRUE") then
   eventually number of objects in the API grows and slows down the transfer rate.

Another option we looking into is to have separate Endpoints on the API to show list of deleted objects only (is this the pattern that anyone uses?).

I'm looking for most "RESTful way" to delete local objects.

Answer (score 2):

The way I handle it is a variation on your #1: each item has a `last updated` field in the database, and if something is deleted, I make an entry in another table of deleted items, and it's updated value is when it was deleted.

The client makes a request asking for "changes since X" which is their own locally stored `last updated` value...it returns new data, and an array of deleted items. Then on the client I purge those values

Comment: Do you keep array of deleted objects in the same endpoint or have separate one? For deleted objects do you keep the whole object or your deleted object has just primarykey + lastupdated?

Comment: same endpoint, it just returns something like: `{"delta": [{"id": 1,"price": 15},{"id": 3,"price": 14}],"deleted": [{"id": 2}]}` and then on the client, it loops through the delta array, doing an `INSERT OR UPDATE` behavior, then loops through the deleted array, deleting those entries from the local DB (I'm usually using SQLite on iOS devices). Since the goal of deletion is elimination, I don't see value in storing more than the primary key, but perhaps there are implementations where that would be valuable

Comment: oh, that was not a real response, in the delta entries I would also have each entries last updated value...

Answer (score 1):

Stale data is always a problem with client/server applications.  If clients loads some data, then some object is deleted on the server, and then client sends a DELETE request, the RESTFul thing to do would be to return a 404, which indicated "not found".  If the client knows that if it sends a DELETE, and gets a 404, the resource was deleting from underneath...

Comment: Could you please explain this: Why client would send "DELETE" request? Client doesn't know that object needs to be deleted... or do you mean if client didn't receive the object it should make a "DELETE" request? I'm looking for most RESTful approach for this issue so your answer is interesting.

Comment: Im talking about if the client loads data, so it sees a resource, then somehow that resource gets deleted on the server without cients knowledge, THEN client tries to delete...

Comment: I checked my API and it shows "HTTP/1.0 410 GONE" for deleted objects which I think is similar to what you saying, so this is helpful. **Now is there anyway to determine deleted objects when I'm working with list endpoints not just individual objects?***

Answer (score 0):

What if you think of your resource not as a list, but rather as a changeset?

Eg. changesets what you have in git or SVN.

This way, there's always a "head" version, and the client always has some version, and the resource is the change between client's last and head.

That way you can apply whatever you've learned by examining/using version control systems.

If you need anything more complex, the science behind is called Operational Transformation (OT) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation

Comment: I was thinking about this option as well but it seems to be pretty complex if implemented from scratch and I'm hoping there is more "RESTful way" to do this.